# gsoap c++ android device encoding

Tags: c++, gsoap

8.15,

I can connect my microsoft web service and I can insert record with this service easily.
I get a confirmation code as a response for record insert. But I have a problem with encoding. The response message must like this `1Exa9GwOIO6pP35l4TJ1Bw==` but instead of this I get a response like this  `4�� u @`

When I try this service on a browser I get the expected response as 
in `1Exa9GwOIO6pP35l4TJ1Bw==`

But when I try it on an android device with gsoap I get a response such as this one `4�� u @`

How can I solve this encoding problem?

```
    TheGameSoapProxy service; 


    _ns1__PlayerRegisterResponse* response = new _ns1__PlayerRegisterResponse();


    std::string telNO =m_pEditTel->getText();
    std::string telefonIME = "111";
    std::string simCardID = "222";
    std::string Username = m_pEditName->getText();
    std::string takim = Takim.c_str();


    _ns1__PlayerRegister* ps = new _ns1__PlayerRegister();


    ps->telefonNumarasi =  &telNO;
    ps->telefonIME =  &telefonIME;
    ps->simCardID =  &simCardID;
    ps->Username =  &Username;
    ps->takim =  &takim;

    if (service.PlayerRegister(ps, response) == SOAP_OK)
    {
       string *ptrSonuc = response->PlayerRegisterResult;
       CCLog( (char*)ptrSonuc );
    }
```

Comment: Yes it is encoding issue. Can you show your codes ?

Comment: what is `string` (not `std::string`)?

Comment: above there is a   using namespace std;, string and std:string must be same.

Comment: I found a possible solution in the following url but when I apply  this solution in this link I am getting this error : soapH.h:2187:87: error: 'xsd__wstring' does not name a type  http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/152026/How-do-I-make-GSOAP-support-Unicode?msg=4176154#xx4176154xx

Answer (score 0):

As per other question here on SO:

add the line below to your typemap.dat file:

```
xsd__string   = | wchar_t* | wchar_t*
```

And then use wstrings instead of strings.